# Google Chrome - HTML5 audio and WAV files

Tags: html, audio

I am using HTML5 audio tag to link to a WAV file, but it suddenly seems to be failing. Chrome does not seem to be able to play WAV files (MP3 works fine). I get an error message like:

```
Error loading: "blob:http%3A%2F%...."
```

Does Chrome's audio tag support WAV? For e.g., try playing this: http://www.nch.com.au/acm/11kulaw.wav

I am on Chrome version 15.0.874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't get the error in Chrome, but the file does not play. The control is visible, but is not working.

There is a bug report in Chromium project that seems to talk about the behavior:
http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=83323

The gist of it is that .wav can mean a bunch of things and have various encodings. The comments recommend using a plugin to handle this or downloading the file.

For the purposes of serving it on the web, I'd recommend compressing it to an MP3 and an OGG format (if you want to be nice to FOSS people) and including multiple source tags.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with an mp3 audio file that did not play just in Google Chrome (this problem could be happening with other audio format files too, like wav or ogg).
I opened my mp3 file in an audio editor (Audacity) and saved it again in the desired format (in this case, *.mp3).
It works correctly in Google Chrome.

My conclusion: if the audio file does not play, the problem is in the settings that generated the audio. Use another program, with other settings.