# How to play a wav file using soundmanager2?

Tags: javascript, wav, soundmanager2

In my application I am using soundmanager2 plugin for playback, mp3 files are playing well but wav files are not playin.

my code as follows

```
   soundManager.createSound({
                  id: 'playback',
                  url: '/music.wav',
                  autoPlay: true,
            });
```

Exception as follows:

```
 HTML5::loadstart: playback
 Media resource http://localhost:3000/music.wav could not be decoded.

 HTML5::error: 3
 SMSound._onload(): "playback" failed to load? - /music.wav
```

whether soundmanager2 supports wav files?

Comment: Flash doesn't play WAV (afaic), and HTML5 doesn't seem to like them in some browsers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8440178/google-chrome-html5-audio-and-wav-files. Why wouldn't you just use MP3, as the files are also much smaller?

Comment: I am using wav for txt to speech conversion so only, is there any other plugin supporting wav?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `type="audio/wav"` to the element playing.

"Firefox supports 8-bit and 16-bit PCM, but not other bit depths (12, 20, 24, 32)."

This might also be your problem in what bitrate your text to speech works at, if that can be changed.

Try changing your text to speech code, it seems that it's very possible (through quick searches) to run text to speech into other formats that all browsers support.

Finally, if you must keep your method, run a server-side separate bit of code to simply convert your wav file into say, ogg and aac and list multiple sources so that all browsers support it.